# Simple OOPS demo, stuck with the function of for loop and its role in the main method

Tags: java, for-loop, oop, methods

The only information about this code is this CreditCard class defines
credit card objects that model a simplified version of traditional credit cards. They
store information about the customer, issuing bank, account identifier, credit limit,
and current balance. They do not charge interest or late payments, but they do
restrict charges that would cause a card’s balance to go over its credit limit.
The following code is from the book Data Structures and Algorithms in java:
Please help me regarding the for loop which is:

```
for (int val = 1; val <= 16; val++) {  
     wallet[0].charge(3*val);
     wallet[1].charge(2*val);
     wallet[2].charge(val);
}
```

Why the charge method has parameters 3*val, 2*val and val. What this loop really does?
From the following code:

```java
package com.illustrations;

public class CreditCard{
    
    private String customer;
    private String bank;
    private String account;
    private int limit;
    protected double balance;

    public CreditCard(String customer, String bank, String account, int limit, double balance){     
        this.customer = customer;
        this.bank = bank;
        this.account = account;
        this.limit = limit;
        this.balance = balance;    
    }
    
    public CreditCard(String customer, String bank, String account, int limit) {
        this(customer, bank, account, limit, 0.0);
    }
    
    public String getCustomer(){ return customer; }
    public String getBank() { return bank; }
    public String getAccount() { return account; }
    public int getLimit() { return limit; }
    public double getBalance() { return balance; }

    public boolean charge(double price) {
        if(price + balance > limit)  
            return false;
        balance = balance + price; return true;
    }
    
    public void makePayment(double amount) {
        balance -=amount;
    }
     
    public static void printSummary(CreditCard card) {
        
        System.out.println("Customer ="+card.customer);
        System.out.println("Bank ="+card.bank);
        System.out.println("Account ="+card.account);
        System.out.println("Balance ="+card.balance);       
        System.out.println("Limit ="+card.limit);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         CreditCard[ ] wallet = new CreditCard[3];
         wallet[0] = new CreditCard("John Bowman", "California Savings", "5391 0375 9387 5309", 5000);
         wallet[1] = new CreditCard("John Bowman", "California Federal", "3485 0399 3395 1954", 3500);
         wallet[2] = new CreditCard("John Bowman", "California Finance", "5391 0375 9387 5309", 2500, 300);
        
         for (int val = 1; val <= 16; val++) {  
         wallet[0].charge(3*val);
         wallet[1].charge(2*val);
         wallet[2].charge(val);
         } 
         
         for (CreditCard card : wallet) {  
             CreditCard.printSummary(card); // calling static method
         
             while (card.getBalance() > 200.0) {  
                  card.makePayment(200);
                  System.out.println("New balance = " +card.getBalance());
             }
         
         }    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see much significance. Actually, there are 3 kinds of wallets defined - **Savings**, **Federal**, and **Finance** with **Savings** having the largest credit limit of the remaining two. So what we did here in the for loop with `3*val` is keep putting in money in the **Savings** wallet thrice as fast as the Finance one because its limit is much higher.
Once the limit has been reached, we don't allow more money to be added in the wallets.

Comment: But why it goes from 1 to 16 specifically? And how come it's putting money in three different accounts...? Can one credit card be linked to multiple accounts? Could you please clarify?

Comment: There are 3 different kinds of credit cards, each linked to a different account. The credit card here is an Object having information for the account no, customer, etc, it's linked to.
And 16 seems like an arbitrary no. to me with no significance here. You can change 16 to some other no. like 5 and it won't really make a difference except the balance in the card may change.

Comment: If I put 32 instead of 16(balance increases from 0 to 1584), it will make payment of 200 seven times until the balance gets less than 200.. Isn't it wierd? Because that's not the purpose of the logic. If I make 16 as 5, like you said, payment will not be possible, as the balance will increase from 0 to just 45. what do you think?